# When does this weaker version of this inequality become an equality?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, quantum-mechanics

Let $A$ and $B$ be Hermitian operators and $\langle \rangle $ be the usual quantum mechanics inner product. We know from the inequality that:

$$  |\langle A B\rangle| \leq  \left\langle A \right\rangle \left\langle B \right\rangle $$

But a weaker inequality would be:

$$ \implies \Re(\langle A B \rangle) \leq |\langle A B\rangle|  \leq  \left\langle A\right\rangle \left\langle B \right\rangle $$

$$ \implies \Re(\langle A B \rangle) \leq   \left\langle A\right\rangle \left\langle B \right\rangle $$

But when does this weaker version of this inequality become an equality?

$$ \Re(\langle A B \rangle) = \left\langle A\right\rangle \left\langle B \right\rangle $$

Comment: Does $A= k B$ where $k>0$ work?

Comment: what's $⟨A⟩$ ? you mean $|A|$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have confused somethings and have now retyped the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it is common in the proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to note that we can only have
$$
|\langle A \mid B \rangle| = \langle A\rangle \langle B \rangle
$$
if $A$ and $B$ are multiples of each other.  That is, either $A = 0$ or $B = kA$ for some $k \in \Bbb C$.

Note however that we can only have $\Re(\langle A \mid B \rangle) = \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle$ if we also have $|\langle A \mid B \rangle| = \langle A\rangle \langle B \rangle$, which is easy to see from your $3$-part inequality.  So, if $\Re(\langle A \mid B \rangle) = \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle$, we may conclude that $A$ and $B$ are multiples of each other.

Use the above to conclude that
$\Re(\langle A \mid B \rangle) = \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle$ if and only if $A = 0$ or $B = kA$ for some $k \in \Bbb R$.